# generics paraemeterised definition in inteface and implementation class rationale

Tags: java, generics, subtyping

I'm unable to understand the concept behind the subtyping / interface implementation in relation to generics. Please explain.
I had the below structure:

```
`ICommand -> ProducerConsumerCommand`

IProducerConsumer -> SimpleProducerConsumer
```

My understanding is that any concrete class implementing IProducerConsumer must hold objects of type T which is the subclass of Number and ICommand interface.

`IProducerConsumer<T extends Number,ICommand>`

Now I want to write a implementation class SimpleProducerConsumer,

Now my intent is that I want to tell that SimpleProducerConsumer can hold any type parameters as defined in IProducerConsumer type parameters as below:

```
public class SimpleProducerConsumer<T,ICommand> implements Runnable,
        IProducerConsumer<T,ICommand> {
```

It dosen't work, it says as below:

```
SimpleProducerConsumer<T,ICommand> - ICommand complains (warning) that it is getting hidden.
IProducerConsumer<T,ICommand> - compiler errors in T saying as below
```

*Bound mismatch: The type T is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter  of the type `IProducerConsumer<T,ICommand>*`

So, My first question is why can't I define the same way as interface in concrete class.
what is happening under the hoods.

if I can define

```
 public class test<ICommand> {}
```

why can't I do the same while implementing, confusing.

Now I define as below

```
public class SimpleProducerConsumer<T,ProducerConsumerCommand> implements Runnable,
        IProducerConsumer<T,ICommand> {
```

Still T in IProducerConsumer complains.

If I change as below:

```
public class SimpleProducerConsumer<T,ProducerConsumerCommand> implements Runnable,
        IProducerConsumer<T extends Number,ICommand> {
```

extends complains saying to remove the token.

Now i do like this as below:

```
public class SimpleProducerConsumer<T extends Number,ProducerConsumerCommand> implements Runnable,
        IProducerConsumer<T extends Number,ICommand> {
```

Still extends in IProducerConsumer dosen't work.

Now

```
public class SimpleProducerConsumer<T extends Number,ProducerConsumerCommand> implements Runnable,
        IProducerConsumer<T,ICommand> {
```

Yes now compiler is happy. Now I'm completely lost, what does above thing mean. SimpleProducerConsumer contains objects of type T which are subclass of Number and ProducerCommand object makes sense, but IProducerConsumer holds objects of Type T ??? what is this ?

What is the rationale behind this. Can someone please expalin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here:

1. As it is declared now in `IProducerConsumer<T extends Number,ICommand>`, `ICommand` is not referencing your `ICommand` interface, but is instead just another generic type parameter declaration like `T`. Therefore you get the warning, that this generic type parameter is hiding your `ICommand` interface. You must declare your `IProducerConsumer` like so:

   ```
   public interface IProducerConsumer<N extends Number, C extends ICommand>
   ```
2. You get a `Bound mismatch` for `T`, because `T` does not necessarily extend `Number`, as required by the `IProducerConsumer` interface. To fix this, you must declare your `SimpleProducerConsumer` like so:

   ```
   public class SimpleProducerConsumer<N extends Number, C extends ICommand> implements Runnable, IProducerConsumer<N,C>
   ```

Comment: Hi balder first thing I'm unclear about the terminology in the above point 1 you said generic type argument, Is it generic type parameter or generic type argument. Because from the link below generic type argument is the one that occurs while invoking the type parameter.http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Comment: Well spot - this was a typo. `ICommand` is actually a type parameter declaration. I edited my answer

Comment: Thanks balder Now I got it. It means that type parameter is a declaration saying that it holds the objects of some type but as ICommand is a type of interface it dosen't make any sense so in terms of generic terminology we have to specify it as it will hold any objects of some concrete type or of type C which extends of the type parameter which is an interface. It makes sense. Thank you. Correct me If my understading has any flaws.

Comment: Point 2 still not clear. Whats wrong like this public class SimpleProducerConsumer<N extends Number, C extends ICommand> implements Runnable, IProducerConsumer<N extends Number,C extends ICommand> I mean I'm saying that SimpleProducerConsumer is holding the objects of some type and implementing interface of exactly same type as declared.

Comment: Here you first declare the two type parameters `N extends Number` and `C extends ICommand`. After this declaration you must reference these type parameters by there simple names `N` and `C`, when they are used as type arguments like e.g. in `IProducerConsumer<N,C>`.